# How to pass parameters to forked test processes in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am running UI tests in parallel with Gradle:

**build.gradle:**

```
test {
  maxParallelForks = 4
}
```

I want to pass a *number of process* (1,2,3,4) to each of these forked processes?

The goal is to make these tests use different virtual displays. So that these UI tests would not conflict with each other. Ideally I would like to pass system property **DISPLAY=:15:1**, **DISPLAY=:15:2**, **DISPLAY=:15:3**, **DISPLAY=:15:4** to forked processes.

Comment: At the moment you can't pass system properties dedicatedly to forked process. You will probably have to implement this functionality on the test class level.

Comment: ok, thank you. No, unfortunately it cannot be implemented in test class. The system property must be set before forking the process. It can only be implemented inside Gradle tests runner.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be a necroposter, but I had same problem (how to utilize forked process as *index*) and managed to solve it, so maybe solution below will help someone.

From [mrhaki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48784900/5837845) on similar question, Gradle will propagate unique `org.gradle.test.worker` property to each forked JVM. Unfortunately for me, these worker properties do not start from 1 (so cannot be directly used as index values), but I figured out that they come in sequence. E.g. for `maxParallelForks = 3` there can be `org.gradle.test.worker = 33`, `org.gradle.test.worker = 34` and `org.gradle.test.worker = 35` per forked process. Thanking to this, we can build indices from workers.

**build.gradle:**

```
test {
    maxParallelForks = 4
    systemProperty 'forks', maxParallelForks
}
```

**somewhere in Java:**

```
Integer maxForks = Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("forks", "1"));
Integer worker = Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("org.gradle.test.worker", "1"));
int index = (worker % maxForks) + 1; // index will be 1, or 2, or 3 or 4
```

Comment: Great! I was looking for this. 
Thank you!