# Gradle equivalent for Maven Surefire surefire.forkNumber

Tags: gradle, junit4

I'm migrating a codebase from Maven to Gradle.
In our integration test we use FailSafe ability to run the tests in parallel in multiple threads.
FailSafe is setting a system property name `surefire.forkNumber` with the number of the specific fork the current thread runs.

Is there equivalent parameter when running JUnit with Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` task in Gradle has the property `maxParallelForks` to instruct the tests to run in parallel. 
To pass a property from the command-line to set the value we can define the following `test` configuration in our build file:

```
// File: build.gradle
...
// Set maxParallelForks using project property
// testMaxParallelForks if set otherwise use 1.
test.maxParallelForks = project.findProperty('testMaxParallelForks') ?: 1
...
```

Then from the command-line we can run the `test` task: `$ gradle test -PtestMaxParallelForks=8`

Gradle sets the Java System property `org.gradle.test.worker` with the index number of the thread running the test. This property can be read and used within the tests that run on the parallel thread.

Comment: thank you, the surefire.forkNumber is actually the running index each thread is assigned so if `maxParallelForks` is set to `3` each of the three threads will have `surefire.forkNumber=1`, `surefire.forkNumber=2`, and `surefire.forkNumber=3`. Do you know if there is anything similar in Gradle's JUnit runner?

Comment: Thanks @mrhaki, it works great. This is the link for the source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:test_execution

Comment: One thing to note is when using Gradle Daemon the number of the worker keep going up, it might be an issue for some implementations.